# Query is too Complex exception in access?

Tags: c#, ms-access, c#-4.0

I am using following functiion to form a query dynamically using fieldId list.

```
    public List<CompareDesignGroup> GroupFields(List<string> fieldIdList)
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                foreach (string fieldId in fieldIdList)
                {
                    sb.Append("'" + fieldId + "',");
                }

                string fieldList = sb.ToString().TrimEnd(',');

                string queryString = "";
                int i = 0;
                foreach(string fieldId in fieldIdList)
                {
                    queryString = queryString + " Select FieldID , CDGroups.Name,
 CDCaption, IIF(ISNULL(Priority),99,Priority), " + i + " from Fields LEFT OUTER 
JOIN CDGroups ON Fields.CDGroupID = CDGroups.CDGroupID 
WHERE Fields.FieldID = '" + fieldId + "' ";
                    if (i < fieldIdList.Count - 1)
                    {
                        queryString = queryString + " union ";
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                queryString = queryString + " order by 4,5 ";
```

//DatReader Reading Part...

```
                dataReader = settingsData.ReadSettingsData(queryString);

                if (!dataReader.HasRows)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                List<CompareDesignGroup> compareDesignGroupList = new List<CompareDesignGroup>();
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    CompareDesignGroup compareDesignGroup = new CompareDesignGroup();

                    compareDesignGroup.CdGroup = dataReader["Name"].ToString();
                    compareDesignGroup.FieldId = dataReader["FieldID"].ToString();
                    compareDesignGroup.CdCaption = dataReader["CDCaption"].ToString();

                    compareDesignGroupList.Add(compareDesignGroup);
                }

                return compareDesignGroupList;
            }
```

When I execute above query with larger number of field elements , MS Access throws an exception as Query is too complex and application stops executing.
Is there any better way of writing above query?
or Is there any way of avoiding this exception?

Comment: Is the union really necessary? Couldn't you just write WHERE Fields.FieldID in (" + String.Join(",",fieldIdList) + ")" or something along that line?

Comment: How many items are in your `fieldIdList`?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at [Microsoft Access query limits](http://www.databasedev.co.uk/access_specifications.html#content3), you can find that number of `And` or `Or` in possible queries limited to 99, your `union` works like `Or` in where clause, so if the number of your unions are bigger than 99, means count of your list, it will throw an exception, but I'd suggest try using `In` instead of `union` but if the size of your query is big, this wont work, and best possible option for your will be using paging, means call it for list of size 100, show result, during representing result again call it for next 100 items and so on.